# Is there anyway to restrict memory usage of jvm thread?

Tags: java, jvm, rhino

I use [mozila rhino](https://github.com/mozilla/rhino) to provides user JavaScript customization capabilities. But if user create a large object in JS, it will cause jvm oom error. For performance reasons, I don't want to put user JS run in a separate jvm process. So I want to find a way to restrict memory usage of jvm thread.

```
// user js like this
test();

function test(){
   var arr = [];
   while(true){
       arr.push("test string");
   }
}
```

PS: Rhino is a JS execution engine written in java. It will compile js into java and run it in the jvm process.

Informations I have found so far:

1. There are many ways to calculate Java object memory usage, like [ehcache sizeof](https://github.com/ehcache/sizeof). But it can only calculate memory of a java object, not work in this scenario. Because the memory is allocated within a method.
2. I found a [sandbox](https://github.com/javadelight/delight-rhino-sandbox) for rhino, but it can only restrict cpu usage.

Maybe if there are anyway to calculate memory usage during thread running, I can block it during user code execution. Can anyone give some advice or ideas?

Comment: Javascript is not Java ... and most Javascript interpreters don't involve JVMs.   But ... no ... JVMs don't have a way to limit the heap usage of individual threads.

Comment: @StephenC Maybe you haven't used rhino, rhino will compile js into java code and run in jvm process.

Comment: Either way, the answer is still no.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893727